# Most Likely Word Based on Max Levenshtien Distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I have a `list` of words:

```
lst = ['dog', 'cat', 'mate', 'mouse', 'zebra', 'lion']
```

I also have a `pandas` dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'input': ['dog', 'kat', 'leon', 'moues'], 'suggested_class': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']})

input   suggested_class
dog          a
kat          a
leon         a
moues        a
```

I would like to populate the `suggested_class` column with the value from `lst` that has the highest levenshtein distance to a word in the `input` column. I am using the `fuzzywuzzy` package to calculate that.

The expected output would be:

```
input   suggested_class
dog          dog
kat          cat
leon         lion
moues        mouse
```

I'm aware that one could implement something with the `autocorrect` package like `df.suggested_class = [autocorrect.spell(w) for w in df.input]` but this would not work for my situation.

I've tried something like this (using `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz`):

```
for word in lst:
    for n in range(0, len(df.input)):
        if fuzz.ratio(df.input.iloc[n], word) >= 70:
            df.suggested_class.iloc[n] = word
        else:
            df.suggested_class.iloc[n] = "unknown"
```

which only works for a set distance. I've been able to capture the max distance with:

```
max([fuzz.ratio(df.input.iloc[0], word) for word in lst])
```

but am having trouble relating that to a word from lst, and subsequently populating `suggested_class` with that word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention `fuzzywuzzy`

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
df['suggested_class']=df.input.apply(lambda x : [process.extract(x, lst, limit=1)][0][0][0])

df
Out[1365]: 
   input suggested_class
0    dog             dog
1    kat             cat
2   leon            lion
3  moues           mouse
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I had seen the `process` module, but didn't realize you could pass the distance method through `scorer=` which in my case i need to use `token_set_ratio`!

Comment: @Luxo_Jr glad I could help :-)